# how to get the size of array inside a hashmap in java

Tags: java

I have a new `ArrayList` inside a `HashMap`, but i don't know how to calculate the size of `ArrayList` inside the `HashMap`

```
Map<String, List<fruit>> groupbyregion = new HashMap<>();
for (fruit s : ll) {
    if (!groupbyregion.containsKey(s.getRegionName())) {
        groupbyregion.put(s.getRegionName(), new ArrayList<>());
    }
    groupbyregion.get(s.getRegionName()).add(s);
}
System.out.println("Group by region: " + groupbyregion);
```

Comment: groupbyregion.get(s.getRegionName()).size()

Comment: Hint: read about Java naming conventions. Class names go UpperCase. Variable names should go camelCase. Always.

Comment: groupbyregion.get(s.getRegionName()).size()  which goes upto end i want to print only once at last iteration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already using:

```
groupbyregion.get(s.getRegionName()).add(s);
```

This calls the **add()** method of the ArrayList in that map slot.
Thus:

```
groupbyregion.get(s.getRegionName()).size();
```

gives you the size.

Beyond that: you want to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45459014/should-i-use-put-or-putifabsent-after-using-getordefault) for how to create lists within maps in more elegant (java8) ways.

Comment: groupbyregion.get(s.getRegionName()).size()  which goes upto end i want to print only once at last iteration

Comment: See your title: *how to get the size of array inside a hashmap in java*. This is exactly what this answer answers.