# Method put() in java Map of type <<String>,List<String>>

Tags: java

How can I put in a map of above type. I do not want to overwrite existing mapping.

**So far my code is:**

```
public class Store {

  Map<String, List<String>> items;

  public Store(){
     items = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
  } 

  public boolean containsKey(String key) {
     return items.containsKey(key);
  }

   public void put(String key, String item) {
      List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
      if (myList == null) {
        myList = new ArrayList<String>();
        items.put(key, item);
      }
  }

}
```

I stopped here because I received an error message stating "change the item type to list String from String". I can not figure out if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: change `items.put(key, item);` to `items.put(key, myList);`

Answer (score 4):

Here, double wrong:

```
 List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
 if (myList == null) {
   myList = new ArrayList<String>();
   items.put(key, item);
 }
```

`myList` will never be null, you just assigned a list to it! And `item` is just a single string, so you shouldn't use it as value for a map that expects lists of strings as value!

You go:

```
  List<String> myList = items.get(key);
  if (myList == null) {
    myList = new ArrayList<String>();
  }
  myList.add(item);
  items.put(key, myList);
```

instead.

Meaning: first you check if you already have a list for that key. If not, you create an empty one. Then you add your new item to the (potentially new) list. Before finally putting the list into the map (it could be already there, but then you just overwrite that information with "itself").

And if you want to know how the "pros" solve this problem, have a look at this [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45459014/should-i-use-put-or-putifabsent-after-using-getordefault) and the answers I received upon asking it.

Comment: How can i check if a key already exist and avoid overwriting its value ?if (ingredients.containsKey(key)) {
     System.out.println(key + "THIS KEY ALREADY EXIST");
    } will this work ?

Comment: @randomguy I don't understand. The whole point of your `put` implementation is that it will *always* add new strings in case the KEY is already known. In other words: if you want your public contract to be different (like: not allowing to update already stored entries), then you should rename your method, and say call it `putIfAbsent()` and throw an exception in case the key is already known. In other words: step 1 is to get 100% clear on the exact requirements you intend to solve with your code. And that is something that only you can do, I dont know the problem you want to solve.

Comment: I am also confused :( . I have been asked to do this.         " Write a method void put(String key, String item) that creates a new mapping from key to ingredient (note that it should not overwrite existing mappings but add to them); "

Comment: @GhostCat It is you the chief ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Or use [`Map.computeIfAbsent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) that is designed for this requirement : add a new entry if not existing mapping for a specific key and getting the value for (the new one or the existing) :

```
items.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>())
     .add(item);
```